# Fabric: how to prompt the user for input between hosts defined in env.roledefs?

Tags: python, fabric

When deploying to the production environment, I want to pause after each server to check if the deployment went as planned on THAT ONE SERVER before Fabric continues to the next server.

This is how I have defined the roles:

```
 def dev():
     """Development Environment
     """
     env.environment='dev'
     env.roledefs = {
            'backend': ['dev_back1', 'dev_back2'],
            'fronts': ['dev_front1','dev_front2','dev_front3']
            }

 def stage():
     """Stage Environment
     """
     env.environment='stage'
     env.roledefs = {
             'backend': ['stage_back1', 'stage_back2'],
             'fronts': ['stage_front1','stage_front2','stage_front3']
             }


 def prod():
     """Production Environment
     """
     env.environment='prod'
     env.roledefs = {
             'backend': ['prod_back1', 'prod_back2'],
             'fronts': ['prod_front1','prod_front2','prod_front3']
             }
```

Like that it executes on all the servers, **but** in the production environment I do want interaction between the administrator and Fabric.

**Like this:**

prod_front1 completed, do you wish to continue to prod_front2?

and when that's done:

prod_front2 completed, do you wish to continue to prod_front3?

Answer (score 1):

## This works, but surely not the best:

def deploy_this_server()

```
    do_deployment_stuff()

    answer = query_user_function("Server done. Continue to next server?")

    if answer == "no":
        sys.exit()
```

front_machines = env.roledefs['fronts']

for front_machine in front_machines:

```
    env.host_string = front_machine

    deploy_this_server()
```